# Exclude weekends from strtotime

Tags: php

I want to only show weekdays (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri) in this snippet:   `<?=date('D M, d', strtotime('+3 days'))?>`

I'm having trouble knowing what to search for in StackOverflow. My searches for "Calculate future date based on business days" or "Checking if date is weekend PHP" isn't yielding what I can understand to move forward.

Use Case: As a customer, I want to know how soon I receive service. This code will show me when I can get service, 3 weekdays days out (even on holidays).

I found this, http://php.net/manual/en/intlcalendar.getdayofweektype.php but I am still stuck :(

Comment: There isn't any native PHP function that will do this for you, but I implemented the [MS Excel NETWORKDAYS() function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7) in PHPExcel, which does this.... https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation/DateTime.php#L932

Comment: So if you say `+3 days` does that mean if the date is a weekend you want to advance to Monday or do you not want to count weekends at all? For example if it is Thursday and you say `+3 days`, does that count `Friday, Saturday, Sunday` and change to `Monday` or does that only count `Friday, Monday, Tuesday` and return Tuesday?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying question. I want to only advance on weekdays (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri). +3 on Saturday would return Wednesday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want weekdays then strtotime can do this.

```
date('D M, d', strtotime('+3 weekdays'))
```

Relative Date/Time Formats:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. Does `weekdays` consider Friday a weekday?

Comment: Yes, weekdays are Monday-Friday, inclusive.